# Is it possible to detect when a Operator preset is loaded prior to execute()?

Tags: python, scripting, operator

Hello folks I have an operator that has the `'PRESET'` `bl_option` for being able to save the properties as a preset.

I'm using a bool property that acts as a flag that helps me to disinguish when the values "comes" from a preset or not (so if they came from a preset, I execute some configuration).

I'd like to know when we have clicked a preset and loaded its values, so I can determine to run or not some code.

If I hover the Operator Presets, I get the menu: `WM_MT_operator_presets`
[image: enter code here]

But not sure what to do with it, I've found nothing in the API.

Any idea?